# Логическая ошибка в коде?

Tags: java, массивы, логика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите исправить код чтобы работал правильно -

```
Определения: (Идет работа с массивом от первого до последнего поля)
             Массив -  
             Резко падает = 88,55,33,22,1; (может быть массив в два поля = 1,4);
             Резко возрастает = 1,15,33,44; (может быть массив в два поля = 5,2);
             Монотонно возрастает = 1,3,15,15,33,55;
             Монотонно падает = 88,55,33,33,22,1; 

Задание:
if toschka == true && vvod == резко возрастает, End = true;
if toshka == false && vvod == резко падает, End = true;
if (toschka == false || toschka == true) && (vvod == null || vvod.length == 0), End = false;
if (toschka == false || toschka == true) && vvod.length == 1, End = true;
```

Мой код, где я накосячил?

```
  public static boolean End(int[] vvod, boolean toschka) {
        boolean Otvet = false;
        boolean dvoinoeVosvr = false;
        boolean vozvrastanie = false;
        int a = 0;
        while (a < vvod.length) {//Pruef ob monoton steigend
            for (int j = 0; j < vvod.length; j++)
                for (int k = j + 1; k < vvod.length; k++) {
                    if (k != j && vvod[k] == vvod[j]) {
                        dvoinoeVosvr = true;
                        break; 
                    }
                }
            for (int i = 0; i < vvod.length - 1; i++) {
                if (vvod[i] > vvod[i + 1]) {
                    vozvrastanie = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    vozvrastanie = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            a++;
        }
      if (vvod == null && vvod.length == 0) {
        Otvet = false;
    } else if (vvod.length == 1){
        Otvet = true;
    } else if (toschka == true && vozvrastanie == true){
        Otvet = true;
    } else if (toschka ==  false && vozvrastanie == false) {
        Otvet = true;
    }
        return Otvet;
    }
}
```

На скриншоте изменены названия метода и переменных метода, код тот же самый

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101309/discussion-on-question-by-str----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С условиями стоит поработать. Во-первых, в условии задачи чётко не определено - значения в массивах обязательно возрастают или убывают, или могут произвольно меняться как в сторону увеличения, так и в сторону уменьшения.

Во втором случае нужно пройтись в цикле и убедиться, что значения меняются в одну сторону на всей протяжённости. Поскольку это не оговорено, будем использовать упрощённый вариант.

Так же чётко не задано условие двойного возрастания. Из кода предположу, что это когда каждое последующее число другое.

**В профессии программиста это важно: 1. запросить все условия. 2. не делать больше чем просят.**

Проверку

```
 if (vvod == null && vvod.length == 0) {
        Otvet = false;
    } else if (vvod.length == 1){
        Otvet = true;
    }
```

Надо перенести в начало метода в таком виде:

```
    if (vvod == null || vvod.length == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (vvod.length == 1){
        return true;
    }
```

Условие здесь стоит поправить. Сейчас вторая проверка свалится с NullPounterException. Если перевести это условие на русский язык: "если ввод равен налл, и его длина равна нулю".

```
if (vvod == null && vvod.length == 0) {
```

Правильное решение:

```
if (vvod == null || vvod.length == 0) {
```

"если ввод равен налл, **или** его длина равна нулю". В случае, если первое условие == true - второе проверяться уже не будет.

**Циклы.**

Тут всё плохо. Один лишний цикл, ненужные проверки, ненужная переменная. Дешевле переписать код:

```
    public static boolean end(int[] vvod, boolean toschka) {

        // (vvod == null || vvod.length == 0), End = false;
        // vvod.length == 1, End = true;
        if (vvod == null || vvod.length == 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (vvod.length == 1) {
            return true;
        }

        // смотрим, есть у нас двойное изменение или нет.
        boolean doubleIncr = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < vvod.length - 1; i++) {
            if (vvod[i] == vvod[i + 1]) {
                doubleIncr = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        //если монотонное - возвращаем false
        if (!doubleIncr) {
            return false;
        }

        // Если первый элемент массива меньше последнего - значит возрастает
        boolean increase = vvod[0] < vvod[vvod.length - 1];

        // if toschka == true && vvod == резко возрастает, End = true;
        //if toshka == false && vvod == резко падает, End = true;
        if ((toschka && increase) || (!toschka && !increase)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        // кстати, последние проверки можно упростить до:
        // return (toschka && increase) || (!toschka && !increase);
    }
```

Тесты для проверки:

```
    @Test
    void endTest() {
        assertFalse(end(new int[]{}, false));
        assertFalse(end(new int[]{}, true));
        assertTrue(end(new int[]{0}, false));
        assertTrue(end(new int[]{0}, true));

        assertFalse(end(new int[]{1,2}, false));
        assertTrue(end(new int[]{2,1}, false));
        assertTrue(end(new int[]{1,2}, true));
        assertFalse(end(new int[]{2,1}, true));

        assertFalse(end(new int[]{1,2,2}, false));
        assertFalse(end(new int[]{2,1,1}, true));
        assertFalse(end(new int[]{1,2,2}, false));
        assertFalse(end(new int[]{2,1,1}, true));
    }
```

*Так же советую называть переменные и методы с маленькой буквы.*

Comment: Но почему тогда метод не компилится если перед последней скобкой не стоит return? Что сделать?

Comment: @Str, возвращаемое значение метода - boolean, то есть, при любом условии он должен вернуть либо true либо false. В твоём примере была переменная, значение которой гарантированно отправлялось в конце метода. В моём примере, чтобы код было проще читать, не было множества вложенных if/else, я делаю return сразу, как только могу вернуть значение, не дожидаясь конца метода.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем коде шесть вариантов, когда функция ничего не возвращает, и один - когда что-то возвращает. С этим надо что-то делать. Еще очень мило выглядит проверка параметра на `null` после долгих манипуляций с этим параметром.

Уберите эти условия отовсюду:

```
toschka == true || toschka == false
```

Comment: Учусь только, поэтому много ошибок:) То есть можно вообще точку не использовать или как?

Comment: @Str продумывайте условия в голове. Точка есть, или ее нет. Очевидно, что это высказывание всегда будет истинно.  !A || A = true. Закон логики. Просто для начала пишите программу на листочке, на русском, когда что-то не получается. Сразу все ошибки и увидите

Comment: @Miron Я им все время говорю про листочек. Не хотят.

Comment: Делал я с листочком, просто препод запихивает сложные данные в онлайн тест из -за которых программа "валится" при проверке.. сижу уже второй день без перерыва, решил 2 задания, а это не хочет ни в какую.. как только одно фиксю, вылазит сразу второе (

Comment: @Str как вариант, выводите перед блоками if в консоль значения, которые находятся в выражениях if. После проходитесь с этими значениями в голове по выражениям, и тогда вы сразу заметите ошибку. Некоторые называют этот процесс дебагом